# Populate a ListView

Tags: android

By pressing add button I want the data printed in list view (no matter how many times we press it)
So far I have this: I dont  know where I am making mistake

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText eText;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str = eText.getText().toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, hiworld.class);
                i.putExtra("Name", str);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Next activity:

```
public class hiworld extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView text;
    ArrayList<String> alName=new ArrayList<>();
    ListView list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hiworld);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String strname = i.getStringExtra("Name");
      //  text.setText(strname);
       // alName.add(strname);

      //  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,alName);
        //list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: try this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Initially take the values in an array. Bind them to the any adapter and set the adapter to the listview.

There are many samples . check this 
http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php
http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90

Answer (score 0):

Your commented code looks correct. Just add few more items in ArrayList by,

```
alName.add(strname1);
alName.add(strname2);
alName.add(strname3);
alName.add(strname4);
```

then you will see populating ListView..